# Can a standard user reach a community without authentication?

Tags: user, authentication, community, licenses

So I have a community that can be accessed by users in my org. I want to have them access it without having to login to the community, and just via a button click, on the same session. Is this possible? Will it have any limitations due to the different licenses? Please advice!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can easily do this. Just add there profiles in community and then enable Global Header for them. Then they can access the community.

Create permission sets to easily assign this permission to specific people.

1. From Setup, enter Permission Sets in the Quick Find box, then select Permission Sets.
2. Click New and create a permission set that includes the System Permission View Global Header.
3. Assign the permission set to the appropriate users or profile.

[Global Header](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_communities_implementation.meta/salesforce_communities_implementation/networks_enable_global_header.htm)